# How can avoid taking a trade if the previous one was a loss in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I have a strategy that usually losses in a row 2 to 5 times and has few single losses. My idea was to reduce the position size after I encounter a loss or to avoid trading until I get a win.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have tried the following:

```
if strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades-1) < 0
    // last trade was a loss
    lastTradeWasLoss := true


if strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades-1) > 0
    // successful trade, reset
    lastTradeWasLoss := false

if x and  not lastTradeWasLoss
    strategy.entry...
```

Comment: looks good. we could help you if you edit your question and paste your entire code.